# What is C17 and what changes have been made to the language?

Tags: c, gcc, iso, c11, c17

As I was checking news about GCC 8, I [saw](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=GCC-C17-Support-Coming) that they added support for the 2017 version of the C language (not C++17, really C17). But I can't find any information about it on Internet.

**Is it a new ISO version like C11, or just a codename used by the GCC team for some corrections in their compiler ?**

Comment: You are only allowed to publish up to a certain number (two?) of technical corrigendum (TC) to an ISO standard. If you need to make further correction after having already released x number of TC, a new version of the standard has to be released. I suspect that is the case here.

Comment: @Lundin: There were three TCs for C99 (incorporated into [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)). It's possible the rules have changed since then.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

According to [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2017-10/msg02121.html) reference, `C17` is actually a **bug-fix version** of the `C11` standard with DR resolutions integrated.

> **C17**, **a bug-fix version of the C11 standard with DR [Defect Report] resolutions
>   integrated**, will soon go to ballot.  This patch adds corresponding
>   options `-std=c17`, `-std=gnu17` (new default version, replacing
>   `-std=gnu11` as the default), `-std=iso9899:2017`.  As a bug-fix version
>   of the standard, there is no need for `flag_isoc17` or any options for
>   compatibility warnings; however, there is a new `__STDC_VERSION__`
>   value, so new cpplib languages `CLK_GNUC17` and `CLK_STDC17` are added to
>   support using that new value with the new options.  (If the standard
>   ends up being published in 2018 and being known as `C18`, option aliases
>   can be added.  Note however that `-std=iso9899:199409` corresponds to a
>   `__STDC_VERSION__` value rather than a publication date.)
>
> (There are a couple of DR resolutions needing implementing in GCC, but
>   that's independent of the new options.)

So, there are no new features included in C17.

The [Cppreference (History of C)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/history) says:

> **Future development**
>
> **C17** Next minor C language standard revision, will include all accepted C11 defect reports, but **no new features**.

**UPDATE:**

> - 2018: C17 (ISO/IEC 9899:2018) ([ISO](https://www.iso.org/standard/74528.html) Store) ([Final draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf)) Includes the deprecation of `ATOMIC_VAR_INIT` and the fixes to the
>     following defect reports:
>
> [[DR 400]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 401]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 402]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 403]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm),
>   [[DR 404]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 405]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 406]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 407]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm),
>   [[DR 410]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 412]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 414]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 415]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm),
>   [[DR 416]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 417]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 419]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 423]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm),
>   [[DR 426]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 428]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 429]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 430]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm),
>   [[DR 431]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 433]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 434]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 436]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm),
>   [[DR 437]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 438]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 439]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 441]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm),
>   [[DR 444]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 445]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 447]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 448]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm),
>   [[DR 450]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 452]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 453]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 457]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm),
>   [[DR 458]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 459]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 460]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 462]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm),
>   [[DR 464]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 465]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 468]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 470]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm),
>   [[DR 471]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 472]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 473]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 475]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm),
>   [[DR 477]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 480]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 481]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 485]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm),
>   [[DR 487]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm), [[DR 491]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm)

Comment: Then it's published by ISO, but it's just a bug-fix version. Thanks !

Comment: Just to complement that, there is actually one effective change proposed: the use of `ATOMIC_VAR_INIT` is no more mandatory for the initialization of atomic variables. Plain normal initialization suffices.

Comment: For those who aren't used at reading standard gibberish: DR stands for Defect Report.

Comment: Does C17 yet unambiguously define the behavior of code that uses an aggregate member lvalue to access the storage of the aggregate?  In every version to date, something like `struct foo {int x;} s = {0}; s.x = 3;` would write the storage associated with a `struct foo` using an lvalue of type `int`, but `int` is not one of the lvalue types that may be used to access a `struct foo`.

Comment: The C17 standard is now available for purchase, although I'm not sure why ANSI has raised the price approximately 93% from $60 to $116. 

https://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS%2fISO%2fIEC+9899%3a2011+(R2017)

Comment: @supercat I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. To what ambiguity are you referring? Are you implying that the expression `s.x = 3` is undefined behavior for some reason?

Comment: @ChronoKitsune: The way N1570 6.5p7 is actually written, such a statement would violate a runtime constraint--and thus yield UB--unless member `x` is a character type.  I think the authors of the Standard assumed that compiler writers would handle such cases sensibly whether or not the Standard required them to do so,  and for that particular case they seem to be right.  A good standard, however, shouldn't rely upon such treatment in a day and age where compiler writers regard as insist that they have no obligation to avoid breaking code whose behavior isn't actually mandated by the Standard.

Comment: Fundamentally, N1570 p6.5p7 fails to offer any guidance as to how to reliably determine between actions which compilers should be expected to process reliably and those they shouldn't.  Since there are some cases where code should have clearly defined behavior but violates the constraint in by 6.5p7, the fact that a construct violates 6.5p7 cannot be regarded as a reliably indication as to whether compilers should process it meaningfully.  As it is, gcc and clang seem to treat the rule as "Treat violations as UB except when that'd be so mind-numbingly dumb as to make people throw out 6.5p7"...

Comment: ...but that's really not a good recipe for distinguishing defined and undefined behavior.

Comment: @supercat I think I'm still missing some piece of the puzzle. 6.5.2.3p3 states that the expression `s.x` has the value stored in subobject `x` of object `s` and also states that it's an lvalue because `s` is an lvalue, so by extension `s.x` also is an lvalue. The effective type (6.5p6) of `s.x` is the declared type of the object: `int`. In the case of `3`, the effective type is `int`. One of the requirements of 6.5p7 states that only an lvalue expression with a type compatible with the effective type of the object is allowed to access it. `(int) = (int);`, so I don't see the problem.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune: If the assignment to `s.x` were only regarded as accessing the stored value only of an object of type `int`, and not of a `struct foo`, then `s.x` should be accessible via any lvalue of type `int`, including those of the form `pointerToStructWithCommonInitialSequence->x` but neither gcc nor clang allow that.  The only justification for gcc and clang to optimize there would be if an access to an `int` member of `s` is also an access to a `struct foo`, but that would imply that an access using lvalue `s.x` is only allowed because a compiler opts not to be stupid.

Comment: @supercat You lost me at `pointerToStructWithCommonInitialSequence`. How is your original example without pointers ambiguous? There are no pointers or a common initial sequence involved in `s.x = 3;` so how is it a constraint violation? In what way is `s.x` not simply an `int`?

Comment: @ChronoKitsune: An access to a structure member is *also* an access to the enclosing structure object, and vice versa.  While N1570 gives blanket permission to use lvalues of the enclosing structure type to be used to access members, the blanket permission is (IMHO deliberately) not reciprocal.  I think the clear intention is that a `struct foo` should be accessible via lvalues of type `int` in some circumstances, but I see nothing in N1570 that would identify any circumstances where such accesses wouldn't violate the constraints of 6.5p7.  It sounds like C17 is the same way.

Comment: @supercat Ah, I think I understand what you're saying finally. You're suggesting that `s.x` itself is UB because 6.5p7 only permits you to access object `s` using a type compatible with its own effective type `struct foo` (i.e. only `struct foo`) or an aggregate or union type that includes such a type among its members, meaning you cannot access `s` using its member `x`. In other words, you believe the rules expressed in 6.5p7 contradict the allowed behavior and syntax specified by 6.5.2.3, so `s.x` is ambiguous.

Comment: While you're clearly accessing member `x`, you're also accessing `s` with a type of `int` rather than its only compatible effective type `struct foo`, implying that you cannot ever declare a structure containing a member with a type other than that structure's own type if you ever hope to use it. Simply put, 6.5p7 was created with good intentions, but it fails to achieve its goal and instead makes things more difficult.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune: If compilers only applied 6.5p7 in cases that where lvalues *alias* lvalues of other types which are used to object the same storage (which is hinted at by the non-normative footnote) there would be no problem.  It's been obvious for years, however, that some compiler writers want to apply the rules even in cases which don't involve cross-type aliasing as written, making the Standard's lack of precision a major problem.

Answer (score 40):

`C17` is a “bugfix release” of the C standard how "`M.S Chaudhari`" noticed. However, there is very useful information prepared by `Jens Gustedt` the author of `"Modern C"` book.

---

He identified the following list of changes in `C17` compared to `C11`:

> - **atomics**:  [initialization (7.17.2, 7.31.8)](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2018/08/06/c17-obsoletes-atomic_var_init/), coherence requirements (5.1.2.4), fences (7.17.3 p11), functions or macros (7.17.1 p6), lockfree depends on type (7.17.5 p3), [compare exchange compares memory and not value (7.17.7.3)](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2018/08/20/compare-exchange-compares-memory-and-not-value/),  [atomic_flag (7.17.18)](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2018/08/13/c17-reformulations-for-atomic_flag/).
> - **threads:** [spurious failures (7.26.3.5 p2, 7.26.3.6 p2, 7.26.4.5 p3)](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2018/08/27/spurious-failures-of-thread-functions/), synchronization (7.26.4 p1), thread specific storage (`tss_t`) and thread exit (7.26.5 p3, 7.26.5.5, 7.26.6)
> - [**`_Generic`** (6.5.1.1), **rvalues and qualification**, cast (6.5.4)](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2018/06/15/c17-rvalues-and-function-types-drop-qualifiers/)
> - **alignment:** fundamental alignment (6.2.8), `_Alignas` (6.7.5), `aligned_alloc` (7.22.3.1)
> - **sequence points:** full expressions (6.8 p4), full declarators (6.7..6 p3)
> - **infinite loops** (6.8.5 p6)
> - **reserved identifiers** (7.1.3)
> - **domain or range errors** (7.12.1), `ilogb`, `erfc`, `lgamma`.
> - underspecification of **`clock`** (7.27.2.1)
> - underspecification of **`realloc`** for size 0 (7.22.3.5)
> - **Annex F:** `FLT_ROUNDS` (F.2 p1)
> - **Annex K:** `tmpnam_s`, `snprintf_s`, `sprintf_s`, `vsprintf_s`, `get_s`, `mbstowcs_s`, `wcstombs_s`, `snwprintf_s`, `swprintf_s`, `vsnwprintf_s`, `vswprint_s`, `mbsrtowcs_s`, `wcsrtombs_s`.

Link to the main page [C17](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2018/04/17/c17/).

---

Also, this content will be updated by `Jens` you can follow to update
here [Jeans Gustedt Blog](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/).

**`P.S: before posting all this stuff I received approval from the author.`**

Comment: Very neat book; thanks. It's like an open-access, more systematic, in-depth version of Klemens's _21st Century C_.